# PHP - Avoid all the includes for every page?

Tags: php

I have a user authentication system that I am currently writing. Problem is, I don't want to have to include class x,y,z,etc for every page that I want to use that class for. For example, here is the index page:

```
///////// I would like to not have to include all these files everytime////////

include_once '../privateFiles/includes/config/config.php';

include_once CLASSES.'\GeneratePage.php';

include_once DB.'\Db.php';

include_once HELPERS.'\HelperLibraryUser.php'; //calls on user class
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$html = new GeneratePage();
$helper = new HelperLibraryUser("username","password","email");

$html->addHeader('Home Page','');

$html->addBody('homePage',
'<p>This is the main body of the page</p>'.
$helper->getUserEmail().'<br/>'.
$helper->doesUserExists());

$html->addFooter("Copyright goes here");

echo $html->getPage();
```

As you can see, there are a few files that I need to include on every page, and the more classes I add, the more files I will have to include. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an autoload function, e.g.:

```
function __autoload($f) { require_once "/pathtoclassdirectory/$f.php"; }
```

This way, when php encounters a reference to a class it doesn't know about, it automatically looks for a file with the same name as that class and loads it.

You could obviously add some logic here if you need to put different classes in different directories...

Comment: How does this affect speed? I imagine it's slower than explicitly stating the class path right?

Comment: Oh, and I usually put this function definition in a common file like Click mentioned...

Comment: Thanks guys: awn and Click Upvote! I will do as suggested : )

Comment: I doubt speed will be an issue.  It's a tiny amount of computation to figure out that a class needs to be loaded, and the actual loading isn't any different.  (Haven't benchmarked it, but...)  And the advantage here is that unnecessary classes aren't loaded at all; no need to keep track of which pages need what.

Comment: Great! This function, along with the method mentioned by Click Upvote is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  (I struggled with this same question once upon a time...)

Answer (score 2):

Make a file called `common.php` and put these include statements as well as any other functions/code that you need in every file (such as database connection code, etc) in this file. Then at the top of each file simply do this:

```
<? 
require_once('common.php');
```

This will include all your files without having to include them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended not to use the __autoload() function any more as this feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.. Now the spl_autoload_register() function is what you should consider.

```
    <?php
    function my_autoloader($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    }
    spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
    
    // Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
    });
    ?>
```